# Add multi-column unique constraint on foreign Key using fluent-nhibernate automapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm an NHibernate and fluent-nhibernate newbie. And I've got some problem with unique constraint and nhibernate mapping.

I've got the following part of domain model.

```
public class Batch
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<BatchParameter> BatchParameters {get; set;}
}
public class BatchParameter
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Batch Batch {get; set;}
}
```

I'm trying to use fluent-nhibernate to map it on the db (SQLServer) using automapping.
I want to be set up my db in order to have :

- Primary Keys on the "Id"s properties
- a Foreign Key on the BatchParamets table
- a Unique Constraint on the Batch table on column Name
- a Unique Constraint on the BatchParameters table on columns Name and Batch_Id

So I've written down this code:

```
public class BatchMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<Batch>
{
    public void Override(FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping<Batch> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id( b => b.Id);
        mapping.HasMany<BatchParameter>(p => p.BatchParameters).Cascade.All().Inverse();
    }
}

public class BatchParameterMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<BatchParameter>
{
    public void Override(FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping<BatchParameter> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id( b => b.Id);
        mapping.Map(b => b.Name).Unique();
        //mapping.Map(p => p.Name).UniqueKey("Batch_Parameter");
        //mapping.Map(p => p.Batch.Id).UniqueKey("Batch_Parameter");
    }
}
```

No problems for the primary keys, the foreign key and the first Unique Constraint. A little bit of headache for the Unique Constraint.

Can someone show me the straight way???

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, it looks like you have a copy-and-paste error: `...Map(b => b.Name)...` should go in `BatchMapping`, not `BatchParameterMapping`.

```
public class BatchMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<Batch>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Batch> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(b => b.Name).Unique();
    }
}
```

Next, `BatchParameter.Batch` is a many-to-one relationship from `BatchParameter` to `Batch`, so it should be mapped with `References(...)` instead of `Map(...)`.  You use `References` for foreign keys to another entity and use `Map` for simple properties.

```
public class BatchParameterMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<BatchParameter>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<BatchParameter> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(p => p.Name).UniqueKey("Batch_Parameter");
        mapping.References(p => p.Batch).UniqueKey("Batch_Parameter");
    }
}
```

Finally, you should remove the unnecessary mappings for the `Id` properties and `Batch.BatchParameters`.  Fluent NHibernate's auto-mapping will map them as desired by default.  In your `Override` methods you only need to specify the properties where you want to do something differently than the auto-mapping default, such as specifying unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

If Id and Name are primary keys in your BatchParameter table you would need a composite id.  Also if you want to have a reference back to Batch from your BatchParameter class you will need to use Reference.  The following should be close to what you need:

```
public class BatchParameterMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<BatchParameter>
{
    public void Override(FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping<BatchParameter> mapping)
    {
        mapping.CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Name);

        mapping.References(x => x.Batch);
    }
}
```